# How to make a simple mini map in a html

Tags: javascript, html

Basically I want to try making a simple mini map with HTML,but I cant figure it out.

Can someone give me a sample?

Just 2 image that are the same but with different sizes. One is small and the other is big, And if you click on any coordinates of the small image,the large image the show where you clicked.

I'm still new at HTML and want to learn more, just need a sample so I can analyze on how to make it.

Comment: you should post some code ... did you try something?

Comment: no i didn't... Im not so good with codes

Comment: create img with the small image and a div for the big one. the image needs a eventlistener that calls a function findPosition and the div's background is the big image that get's moves based on the small coordinates.

Comment: hmmm let me try this..

Comment: You should explain more on what you want to do. A game? A geographical map? Something else? If you really don't have much skills in programming, I would say that you need more than a Q&A site.

Comment: A geographical map ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

like i said create a image , find the mouse coordinates over that image.

create a div with the same image and set the background position.

replace YOURMAP with a image.

```
var img,w,h,mu=true,map,MAP='YOURMAP';
function pos(e){
 var x=e.pageX-img.offsetLeft,y=e.pageY-img.offsetTop,
 left=((w/img.width*x)-(map.offsetWidth/2))*-1,
 top=((h/img.height*y)-(map.offsetHeight/2))*-1;
 map.style['background-position']=left+'px '+top+'px';
}
window.onload=function(){
 img=document.createElement('img');
 img.onload=function(){
  w=this.width;h=this.height;
  img.style.width='200px';
 }
 img.src=MAP;

 map=document.createElement('div');
 map.style.background='#000 url('+MAP+') no-repeat 0 0';
 map.style.width='200px';
 map.style.height='200px';

 document.body.appendChild(img);
 document.body.appendChild(map);

 img.addEventListener('mousedown',function(e){
  mu=false;pos(e);e.preventDefault()
 },false);
 img.addEventListener('mousemove',function(e){
  mu||pos(e)
 },false);
 img.addEventListener('mouseup',function(e){
  mu=true
 },false);
}
```

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/m3snq/3/ or http://jsfiddle.net/m3snq/6/

if you don't understand something just ask..

Comment: cool thank you for this... I'm gonna try to recreate this cuz it seems that its not working on jsfiddle

Comment: remove window.onload=function(){}

Comment: yeah but there are 2 demos i made on jsfiddle ... i tested with chrome and they work.what broeser do you use?

Comment: ahh so thats why.. i use mozilla..

Comment: mozilla also should work. check console for errors.

Comment: its still not working.. what do i remove? the whole code and all in between {}?

Comment: you need to find the console. then you see the error it throws.. send it to me and i correct it.in jsfiddle you don'tneed window.onload (check the 2 demos)

Comment: my codes? or the errors?

Comment: in your browser find the console. open it refresh the pageand check for errors.

Comment: we're talking about the demo you linked, right?

Comment: i linked 2 demos.downloading firefox.

Comment: yes the 2 demos, they're not working on jsfiddle. The large image just stays the same.

Comment: replace map.style['background-position'] with map.style.backgroundPosition

Comment: ok. gonna download it

Comment: np.. read my other answers or question most of them talk about javascript and the modern use of it...